# CodeIgniter Thumbnail Prefix instead of suffix

Tags: php, codeigniter, thumbnails

By default in Codeigniter thumbnail names are made by image name and thumb_marker which is added as name suffix.

[image: img]

I want to add `thumb_marker` as a prefix, instead of `mypic_thumb.jpg` i want `thumb_mypic.jpg`.

Comment: There is no option there for thumb changing to prefix http://prntscr.com/3i298g

Comment: Ok thanks, you dont need to do that for me, because i'm not satisfied with editing the core of the framework, i solved this problem by spliting name and extension and putting it in database splited.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no way to configure the position of the `thumb_marker` you will have to extend the library. Fortunately CI [supports this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html) (see the extending code classes part). So what you need to do is the following:

1. Create a new `MY_Image_lib.php` file inside your `application/libraries/` folder (the `MY_` part can be configured too.)
2. Put the following code inside

   ```
   class MY_Image_lib extends CI_Image_lib {

       public function initialize($props = array()) {
           parent::initialize($props);

           $xp = $this->explode_name($this->dest_image);

           $filename = $xp['name'];
           $file_ext = $xp['ext'];

           $this->full_dst_path = 
               $this->dest_folder.$this->thumb_marker.$filename.$file_ext;
       }
   }
   ```

   When in doubt, you can always check the library's source under `system/libraries/Image_lib.php`.
3. Now you can use the Image_lib as before (load it with `$this->load->library()`) and CI will pick up your new extended class.